# Caesar Cipher Not Encrypting

Tags: python, python-3.x, caesar-cipher

Not sure why my code is not encrypting the cipher properly
For example: "Hello how are you" is "2z669 29g vbz i9e" and my code will decrypt it just fine. If I attempt to encrypt it I get:
"e]z } g vbz I e". I am assuming it has to do with the +21 modulus len(ALPHABET) I just figured if the decrypt is subtract I need to add to reverse the cipher, but I guess I am wrong any assistance would be appreciated thanks!

```
ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789."

def encrpytstr(message):
    newString = ''
    #loop to assign new alphabet value
    for index in range(0, len(message)):
        oneLetter = message[index]
        
        #assinging new alphabet value
        newAlphabetValue = (ALPHABET.find(oneLetter.lower()) + 21) % len(ALPHABET) + (ord('A') if oneLetter.isupper() else ord('a'))
        
        #checking for white spaces
        if oneLetter == ' ':
            newAlphabetValue = 32
        
        #creating the new string
        newString = newString + chr(newAlphabetValue)
    
    return newString


def decrpytstr(message):
    newString = ''
    #loop to assign new alphabet value
    for index in range(0, len(message)):
        oneLetter = message[index]
        
        #assinging new alphabet value
        newAlphabetValue = (ALPHABET.find(oneLetter.lower()) - 21) % len(ALPHABET) + (ord('A') if oneLetter.isupper() else ord('a'))
        
        #checking for white spaces
        if oneLetter == ' ':
            newAlphabetValue = 32
        
        #creating the new string
        newString = newString + chr(newAlphabetValue)
    
    return newString


def main():
    message = input("Enter text: ")
    choice = input("(E)ncrypt or (D)ecrypt?: ").upper()
    
    if choice == "E":
        encrpytstr(message)
        newString = encrpytstr(message)
        print(newString)
        input("Press ENTER to exit")
    
    elif choice == "D":
        decrpytstr(message)
        newString = decrpytstr(message)
        print(newString)
        input("Press ENTER to exit")
    
    else:
        print("Invalid Input Try Again!")
        input("Press ENTER to exit")
main()
```

Comment: Perhaps you would be able to debug this yourself. Add `print` statements to see the values of the variables as the program runs, or learn to use a debugger. The canonical link is [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) but it's not particularly suitable for Python.

Comment: already tried to attempt something similar to this, I put a break in the code and ran it step by step, but was still unable to produce a proper solution. Only a possible problem which I posted in the question.

Comment: Please [edit] to demonstrate your debugging efforts.

Comment: To my knowledge, I cannot post screenshots? I am using visual studio code and on line 12 I put a break in my code to allow step by step movement through the code without it compiling all at once.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely [don't post screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors); that's not at all what I asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a couple of print statements reveals a rather fundamental problem with your logic.

```
        #assinging new alphabet value
        newAlphabetValue = (ALPHABET.find(oneLetter.lower()) + 21) % len(ALPHABET) + (ord('A') if oneLetter.isupper() else ord('a'))
        print("input: %s new: %s" % (oneLetter, chr(newAlphabetValue)))
        print("(found %i +21 %i)" % (ALPHABET.find(oneLetter.lower()), ALPHABET.find(oneLetter.lower())+21))
```

produces

```
input: H new: ]
(found 7 +21 28)
input: e new: z
(found 4 +21 25)
input: l new: 
(found 11 +21 32)
input: l new: 
(found 11 +21 32)
input: o new: „
(found 14 +21 35)
input: , new: u
(found -1 +21 20)
input:   new: u
(found -1 +21 20)
input: h new: }
(found 7 +21 28)
input: o new: „
(found 14 +21 35)
input: w new: g
(found 22 +21 43)
input:   new: u
(found -1 +21 20)
input: a new: v
(found 0 +21 21)
input: r new: b
(found 17 +21 38)
input: e new: z
(found 4 +21 25)
input:   new: u
(found -1 +21 20)
input: y new: i
(found 24 +21 45)
input: o new: „
(found 14 +21 35)
input: u new: e
(found 20 +21 41)
input: ? new: u
(found -1 +21 20)
```

Notice how the result from `find` is often -1 and how this throws everything off?

I'm not sure exactly what's wrong because it's not clear how you thought this should work. Perhaps simplify the code so that it's more obvious what's going on and why.

The detour via the `index` is also quite unnecessary; Python is perfectly capable of looping over the items in a list directly. As an aside, probably avoid repeatedly appending stuff to the end of a string if you can.

```
def encrpytstr(message):
    # Use a list for speed
    newletters = []
    for letter in message:
        upcase = letter.isupper()
        letter = letter.lower()
        index = ALPHABET.find(letter)
        if index > -1:
            newindex = (index + 21) % len(ALPHABET)
            # print("input: %s (%i, %i) new: %s (%i, %i)" % (letter, index, ord(letter), ALPHABET[newindex], newindex, ord(ALPHABET[newindex])))
            letter = ALPHABET[newindex]
            if upcase:
                letter = letter.upper()
        newletters.append(letter)
    # now finally do a slow string join
    return ''.join(newletters)
```

I left a commented-out `print` statement in case you want to repeat the debugging step with the new code.

The new code simply preserves verbatim any characters not in `ALPHABET`; it should be easy to see what to change if you don't want that.

Finally, did you misspell "encrpyt" and "decrpyt" on purpose? It's slightly humorous when you first see it, but will bite you in the back side once your code grows. Avoid weird misspellings in function names.